# Gatsby Optimization With Bootstrap + Google PageSpeed Insights

Tags: optimization, gatsby, pagespeed, google-pagespeed, lighthouse

I'm trying to optimize my site in speed using Google PageSpeed Insights/Lighthouse. My current score is around 37, but I think that is mainly due to the large amount of API requests the page does (Around 30-40). [Here's the Google PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Forangecountycovid19.com%2F)

**How do I fix this Avoid Changing critical requests issue?**

[image]

**gatsby-browser.js**

```
// Imports: Dependencies
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

**Layout.js**

```
// Layout
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div className="layout">
      <Helmet>
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        />

        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <title>COVID-19</title>
        <html lang={'en'} />
        <link rel="canonical" href="https://orangecountycovid19.com" />
        <meta name="description" content={'Orange County, CA COVID-19 Tracker'} />
      </Helmet>

      <div>{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

// Exports
export default Layout;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you importing Boostrap in your `gatsby-browser.js` as well as in your `<Helmet>` component using a CDN? You are importing those styles in all your pages with `gatsby-browser` plus each time you render `<Layout>` (in most of your components I guess) since your `<Helmet>` is placed in `<Layout>` component. It's kinda messy.

Since you are using `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` your styles will be placed in all the site. From [Gatsby documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/recipes/styling-css/):

> 1. Create a global CSS file as `src/styles/global.css` and paste the following into the file:
> 2. Import the global CSS file in the `gatsby-browser.js` file such as the following:
>    *Note: You can also make use of `require('./src/styles/global.css')` to import the global CSS file in your gatsby-browser.js file.*
> 3. Run `gatsby-develop` to observe the global styling being applied across your site.
>    *Note: This approach is not the best fit if you are using CSS-in-JS for styling your site, in which case a layout page with all the shared
>    components should be used. This is covered in the next recipe.*

Remove your `<Helmet>` styles and ensure that `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css` has the same styles than `bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css` to avoid a purge. You must minimize as much as possible outside requests, at least of styles that are easy to replace in your project.

With this removal, you will improve outcome request as well as render-block styles.

Your PageSpeed Insights also show a humongous amount of unused JavaScript (almost 1 second).

Comment: Thanks! I removed the Bootstrap CDN link from my helmet and imported it in my gatsby-browser.js only. There was no need for the global.css